# Repo commands not recognized

Tags: git, android-source, linux-mint, repo

I am on Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, and I am running into an issue following the steps to install repo.

My first problem is here;

```
gpg --recv-key 8BB9AD793E8E6153AF0F9A4416530D5E920F5C65
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo.asc | gpg --verify - ~/bin/repo
```

with the first command I get:

```
gpg: key 16530D5E920F5C65: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```

With the second I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1256  100  1256    0     0   3245      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3237
gpg: Signature made Wed 13 Jan 2021 12:12:05 PM EST
gpg:                using DSA key 8BB9AD793E8E6153AF0F9A4416530D5E920F5C65
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
gpg: Signature made Wed 13 Jan 2021 12:12:05 PM EST
gpg:                using RSA key A34A13BE8E76BFF46A0C022DA2E75A824AAB9624
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
gpg: Signature made Wed 13 Jan 2021 12:12:06 PM EST
gpg:                using EDDSA key E1F9040D7A3F6DAFAC897CD3D3B95DA243E48A39
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

If I skip this and try to go straight to the initializing repo client instructions (https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#initializing-a-repo-client) I go to the point of using the repo init command:

````
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifes```
````

And, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

**update**

Ran this command

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

result showing I do have python installed:

```
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.8
```

Comment: Well, `repo` command is recognized, `python` isn't. Install Python 3.

Comment: I ran this command
```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```
And, recieved this result:
```
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.8
```

This tells me that I do have python installed.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution on here somewhere else. I needed to create a 'symlink' according to Francesco Mantovani. I am not sure what this is, so if anyone can expand on this, by explaining what it is I would appriciate it.

Here is the solution

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: A symlink ("symbolic link") redirects from one file to another file. In this case, /usr/bin/python will redirect to /usr/bin/python3.8. So if someone tries to run /usr/bin/python, they will actually run /usr/bin/python3.8. You can also inspect the symlink for example with `ls -la /usr/bin/python`, which should show where it redirects to.